# How to display text in columns ignoring one of this separators?

Tags: bash, printf, echo

This code is to display the content of `str1` in columns:

```
str1='Name: Robert Jhonson  21
Name: Flex Maxed 23
Name: Thisisaverylongname         andlongsurname 44'

IFS=$'\n'

echo "$str1" | column -t
```

Return this:

```
Name:  Robert               Jhonson         21
Name:  Flex                 Maxed           23
Name:  Thisisaverylongname  andlongsurname  44
```

But what I'm trying to do is do not separate the surname in another column.
This is the desired output:

```
Name:  Robert Jhonson                      21
Name:  Flex Maxed                          23
Name:  Thisisaverylongname andlongsurname  44
```

Do you have any idea to do it? Could you give me an example, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using awk:

```
echo "$str1"|awk '{print $1, $2 " " $3, $4}' OFS='\t'
Name:   Robert Jhonson  21
Name:   Flex Maxed      23
```

**EDIT:** Based on edited question:

```
echo "$str1"|awk '{print $1, $2 " " $3, $4}' OFS='\t' | column -ts$'\t'
Name:  Robert Jhonson                      21
Name:  Flex Maxed                          23
Name:  Thisisaverylongname andlongsurname  44
```

Comment: You helped me again, @anubhava! Thanks! :)

Comment: Please check the answer as the correct one, we can help to close questions!

Comment: I was editing the question. I don't mark the correct answer becouse this method does not work in the new case. Thank you all. :)

Comment: Rather than hard-coding the padding of the string, why not just use awk to detect and recreate the delimiting, and then pipe the thing to `column -ts$delimiter`?

Comment: @kojiro: OP wants column #2 and #3 together so I'm not sure which option of `column` will work for that. We can avoid hardcoding by 2 pass awk though.

Comment: ` awk '{print $1, $2 " " $3, $4}' OFS='\t' | column -ts$'\t'`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way in `bash`:

```
$ while read -r title fname lname age; do      
    echo "$title|$fname $lname|$age"
done <<< "$str1" | column -s'|' -t
Name:  Robert Jhonson                      21
Name:  Flex Maxed                          23
Name:  Thisisaverylongname andlongsurname  44
```

While reading you echo the line with new delimiters for `column` to put tabs on. Using `-s` option of `column` you specify the new delimiter.

Comment: Thanks! but I'm afraid using \t is not a great idea in this case. Try the code with the new input of the main post. :(